# How to convert Piecewise into KroneckerDelta form by FullSimplify?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, piecewise

The question comes from the last example of [this topic](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SeriesLimitsAndResidues#28112) in the Wolfram documentation.

```
SeriesCoefficient[E^x^2, {x, 0, n}]
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [wolfram.com](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Files/ConvertingPowerSeriesToNormalExpressions.en/O_6.png))</sub>

However, my (v11.1) output is

$\begin{cases}
\frac1{{\sf Gamma}\left[\frac{2+n}2\right]} &\quad {\sf Mod}[n,2]=0\ \&\&\ n\geq 0 \\
0 &\quad \text{True}
\end{cases}$

Moreover, I think It will be very tedious if specifically writing a bunch of code for each function.

So, are there any easier universal ways by applying options to **`FullSimplify`** such as with `TransformationFunctions`, `ComplexityFunction`?

Thanks!

---

Here are some pre-code:
(f1 ~ f4 are the same in fact)

```
f1 = SeriesCoefficient[E^x^2, {x, 0, n}]
f2 = KroneckerDelta[n~Mod~2]/(n/2)!
f3 = If[Mod[n,2]==0 && n>=0, 1/(n/2)!, 0]
f4 = Piecewise[{{1/Gamma[(n+2)/2], Mod[n,2]==0 && n>=0}}, 0]

s[f_, a_:(t=6)] := SeriesData[x, 0, Table[#1, {n, 0, #2}], 0, #2+1, 1] &[f, a]

{Series[E^x^2, {x, 0, t}], s /@ {f1, f2, f3, f4}} // Flatten

Counts@%
```

Comment: fromPW[Piecewise[{{Gamma[(2 + n_)/2]^(-1), 
     Mod[n_, 2] == 0 && n_ >= 0}}, 0]] := 
 KroneckerDelta[Mod[n, 2]]/(n/2)!;

FullSimplify[SeriesCoefficient[E^x^2, {x, 0, n}], 
 TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, fromPW}]